# Add prefix for each rule in SASS

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

My project uses vuetify and a lot of my own styles.
My styles frequently use `&` multiple times in the style declaration, like so:

```
.sis-sidebar {
  &__link {
    &.-active &-placeholder {
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
}

// Compiles to:

.sis-sidebar__link.-active .sis-sidebar__link-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

It works just fine for the html like that:

```
<div class="sis-sidebar__link -active">
  <div class="sis-sidebar__link-placeholder">
    This one is white
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all my styles to have more priority than the styles from the framework. But I don't want to change anything inside. That's the entry scss file that I'm trying to modify:

```
@import 'framework';
@import 'my-styles';
```

I want all my styles to be prepended with some `#sis` prefix, but only once. If I do

```
@import 'framework';
#sis {
  @import 'my-styles';
}

// It compiles to:

#sis .is-sidebar__link.-active #sis .is-sidebar__link-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

// And I want it to be: 

#sis .is-sidebar__link.-active .is-sidebar__link-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: But it does. https://github.com/Kasheftin/sass-prefix-test. There's #sis at the middle of the string `#sis .is-sidebar__link.-active #sis .is-sidebar__link-placeholder`.

Comment: I think the point is that #sis should appear only once at the beginning, not multiple times. The reason for this is that the ampersand is always being replaced by the complete structure up to the root. This is what you benefit from when using the version of your code without the #sis. You cannot have the best of both worlds however so I would suggest you simplify your selector. This is a good idea anyway since code like that is quite hard to read for most people.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
.sis-sidebar {
  &__link {
    #sis &.-active &-placeholder {
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

You could also avoid this issue altogether by using variables, like this:

```
$sidebar-block: '.sis-sidebar';
$sidebar-element: '__link';

#sis {
  #{$sidebar-block + $sidebar-element}.-active #{$sidebar-block + $sidebar-element}-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that I can modify all my stylesheets to get the task done. I can also replace scss with the plain css everywhere and prepend every rule with #sis. The question is not about modifying all the styles (there's about 500kb of them) - it's about keeping all the old code and somehow update entry file only to get every rule prepended with #sis automatically only once.

Comment: The only way it might work using your import approach is when you transpile the scss to css and then back to scss. Then the code is stripped of all its ampersand selectors and you could prepend it with the id selector. I have no experience with such an approach however so you  will have to try it out.